# Combo box in access referencing multi columns

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combo box on the form which when chosen I'd like to run a select query.

The table which is the source for the query have a number of columns:

```
position name, budget 1, budget 2 budget 3 budget ....budget 12, actual 1, actual 2, 
actual ...12
```

etc.

And now when I click "budget" on the combo box I'd like to run a query which 
will make a table with:

```
position name, budget 1, budget 2, .....budget 12).
```

If I'm not precise please let me know.

Comment: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/access2013 Learn how to use access. Follow a few tutorials. then it'll be easier. But follow tutorials

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I think it might be easiest at this stage of your learning to create the query you want and save that as an object and then open the query using the After Update event of your combo box.

**To create and save a query**:

Go to Create > Query Design

[image]

Select your table and click "Add"

[image]

Double-click each field you want to appear in your query

[image]

Close the query when you're finished and you'll be prompted to save and name it

[image]

The query is then saved and is available to run at anytime you want (just double-click it from the Navigation Pane on the left-hand side):

[image]

**Opening the query from a combo box selection**:

So assuming you've already created your form and added your combo box with an option of "budget" in there somewhere, go in to Design View for your form, select the combo box. With the combo box selected, go to the Event tab of the Property Sheet and click the [...] button of the After Update event:

[image]

Select the "Code Builder" option, which will open the VBA Editor

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

The `Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()` to the `End Sub` lines start and end the code that will run on the After Update event of the combo box.

The After Update event is triggered after data is entered in to the combo box, so whenever you select an option from the combo box, this event is triggered and will run code that is between the 2 lines of code that has already been written for us.

As there is nothing written there at the moment, we will need to write some VBA to get it to do what you're asking.

> when I click "budget" on the combo box I'd like to run a query which
>   will make a table with:
>   `position name, budget 1, budget 2, .....budget 12)`.

So we're half-way there as we've already created the query with the desired output, we just need to open it on the After Update event of the combo box.

To do this we'll check whether the combo box option is set to "budget" and *if* it is, we'll open the query we saved earlier.

An `if` statement and the `DoCmd.OpenQuery` method should help us here:

```vb
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()

    If _
        Me.Combo0 = "Budget" _
    Then

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryBudgets", acViewNormal

    End If

End Sub
```

So now, when you select "Budget" on the form, the query should open.